# C# Drag-Drop - using files on another Window

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I have using Drag-Drop on my WPF application

After dragging images, I have adding file addresses on a List and on another window I try to Crop Images

Everything is fine, except one thing: when I try to visit the folder that contains images, It's not working until I close Crop windows.
Is there any solution that folder works during working on Crop Windows ?

With this code, I have calling Crop Windows

```
Crop objCrop=new Crop();
objCrop.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: `when I try to visit the folder that contains images,` what do you mean by 'visit the folder'?

Comment: @SteffenWinkler Images are on one folder and I have dragging from it

Answer (score 0):

The `ShowDialog()` method won't return until the `Crop` window has been closed. It blocks. If you want to be able to access the other window while the `Crop` window is still open, you should use the `Show()` method:

```
Crop objCrop=new Crop();
objCrop.Show();
```

Comment: Thanks, but still same problem

Comment: What's the problem then? Please provide a reproducible sample of your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve